# What will happen if I flash the Pixel Android P Device image on my Nexus 6P?

Tags: rom-flashing, android-beta-program, 9.0-pie

I just finished watching the Google I/O 2018 keynote and boy did it get me hyped up about Android P! For the last half hour or so I've been scouring the internet looking for some way to flash the latest preview using the Pixel system images here: https://developer.android.com/preview/download

Only problem? I don't own a Pixel device. All I've currently got on my hands is a Nexus 6P which Google recently dropped support for and made no mention of during the keynote.

Which leads me to my question: What will happen if I flash the Pixel Android P preview device image on my Nexus 6P? Will this brick my phone, or will everything still run ok? Now, realistically, I'm not trying to find out if someone has already tried this (duh), but I was hoping someone with a bit more knowledge could tell me if this is even remotely possible.

Answer (score -2):

This is the easiest way to flash Android P to your Nexus 6p. Although it is possible to keep all your files, I recommend a backup in case something goes wrong.

1. [Install Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) on your PC. This will allow you to flash anything you want.
2. Next, download an [image](https://developers.google.com/android/images) of Android P for the Nexus 6p onto your desktop. All images for the 6p are available for download there.
3. Now connect your 6p via USB.
4. Click on "Flash Stock + Unroot" on the toolkit. Select the image you just downloaded (not the images the toolkit offers since those are outdated) then choose whether you want to factory reset the device or not.

Now the toolkit will automatically flash the image you chose onto your machine.

Comment: I don't think the Android P images released for the 6p yet though since there isn't yet an image for it.

Comment: There are definitely other ways to install Android P but I prefer this method since it's very easy to root and install whatever images you want later on as well if you wish to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure you entirely understand my question. Like you mentioned, the Android P images for the 6P haven't been released yet (and there's been no mention of when they WILL be released) but my question is whether or not just using the Pixel device images is an idea worth considering.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm fairly certain the pixel images will work for the pixel phones only. You can find images on XDA that work for the 6p if you're in a hurry.

Comment: So basically the pixel images won't install because it is not compatible.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll just compile the nexus 6P Android P sources myself. ;)